# On change input in parent send val to iframe with update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need update iframe's content on input[text] changed(or on some another event).

For example: I'm typing in parent's input "Hello World!!!", and iframe's `<h1>Hi</h1>` is changing to 
`<h1>Hello World!!!</h1>` symbol by symbol.

Better if solution will be on jQuery, but vanilla js is ok, too))

Thank you very much.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English(

Comment: You have to have CORS access, then  `var otherDocument = iframeElement.contentWindow.document`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @StackSlave iframe`s page and parent is on same server, as far as I know I don`t need CORS in this case

Comment: @Rojo As I said when user typing text in input[type=text] new value goes to iframe and change $("h1").text(); in iframe symbol by symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better way is using Window.postMessage => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

parent Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>a Page..</title>
  <style>
    body  { font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    iframe { width: 300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #4593c6; }
  </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <p>parent input :
      <input id="in-Txt" type="text" placeholder="type something">
      <button id="Bt-Send2iFrame">Send2iFrame</button>
    </p>

    <iframe id="in-Frame" src="xyz_frame.html" ></iframe>

  <script>
    const inText  = document.querySelector('#in-Txt')
        , btSend  = document.querySelector('#Bt-Send2iFrame')
        , inFramW = document.querySelector('#in-Frame').contentWindow

    btSend.onclick=_=>{
      let info = { inTxt: inText.value }

      inFramW.postMessage( JSON.stringify(info), "*")
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <p> the iframe </p>

  <p id="info-Parent">...</p>

  <script>
    const infoParent = document.querySelector('#info-Parent')

    window.onmessage=e=>
      {
      let message = JSON.parse ( e.data )
      infoParent.textContent = message.inTxt
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value on the parent page as a parameter to the iframe.

Say for example the following

Parent HTML,

```
    <input type="text" id="parenteElem">
    <iframe id="frameOnParent">
```

Parent Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $("#parentElem").on("change", function(event) {
               $('#frameOnParent').attr('src', "test.html?param1=" + $(this).val()); 
         })
    </script>
```

Iframe HTML:

```
    <h1>Hi</h1>
```

Iframe Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function getHeader() { 
            var headerText = window.location.search.substring("param1");
            return headerText;
         }

         var heading = getHeader();
         $("h1").html(heading);
    </script>
```

Comment: `heading` will be undefined

Comment: thanks its not ideal but i can wor with it but `getHeader();` must be a `function getHeader() { 
            var headerText = window.location.search.substring("param1"); return headerText;
         }`