# Passing data through an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Im currently building PWA and Im using a wordpress multisite. the main site acts as the UI and all the extensions and features of the other sites within the multisite are displayed on the mainsite via iFrame.

I cant seem to load the content into a `div` and force clicked links to stay inside of that `div`.

What I want to do is pass data through the iFrame to interact with the main UI and pass data via onClick.

IF this is possible how should I do it?

I have a custom built media player that is installed on the main UI and I need a button clicked inside of the iframe to trigger audio and data outside of the iframe into the main window? Is there a javascript for this or something?

Comment: If you have CORS access you get the `var iframeDoc = iframeElement.contentWindow.document` like that. So you would now do `iframeDoc.getElementById()` and the like. Make sure you have a different `var` for every `<iframe>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496098/on-change-input-in-parent-send-val-to-iframe-with-update/58496467#58496467

Comment: @StackSlave What if I wanted to use an Onclick function. something like this : function addSong (song) {
  if (song && song.dataset) {
    const { src, artist, title, album, cover } = song.dataset;
    document.getElementById("cover").innerHTML = cover;
    document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = artist;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("album").innerHTML = album;
  }
}  would i replace the element with addsong? or how would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If that code *(in your comment)* and those nodes are on the `iframeDoc`, then `document.`property should work. If that code is on the `parent` and those nodes are on the `iframeDoc` then you would need to use `iframeDoc.`property. If that code lives on the `iframeDoc`, but those nodes live on the parent page, then you would need to use `parent.document.`property on the `parent` page. Of course, you should learn to separate your HTML from your JavaScript. `someElement.onclick = function(){ addSong(songObject); }`,

Comment: @stackslave this code is on the parent page. Allowing for a button click inside of the iframe to be clicked and transfer the metadata to the parent page. If that makes sense. So that code (in my comment above)goes on the parent page and inside of the iframe document the user will see:      '<button data-src="mysong.mp3" data-artist="artist" data-title="name of the song" data-album="name of album" data-cover="albumcover.jpg" onClick="addSong(this);">Add Song</button>'  and this will trigga the data inside of the iframe to read and display on the parent page. if that is making any sense.

Comment: `this` in an eventListener refers to the Element. I'm pretty sure your button Element is not a song. Get out of the practice of inline Events, anyways. Separate you JavaScript from your HTML.